# How do I correctly apply array and curve modifiers for this object?

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

In my project, curve and array applied and object is in x axis.

That is fine but I want to rotate curve slightly (30º) in edit mode and after that curve modifier deform axis is same but object rotates and I want this object perfectly face x axis you can see in this image[image]. How to do it to align properly?

Comment: The easiest way to fix this would be to parent your arrayed object to the curve, if I've read you right.

Comment: Could you share your Blender file using https://blend-exchange.com/ to give it a try ?